# Глобальное подключение к БД

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Создал config.php в нем прописал подключение к БД:

```
function connectToDB() {
    global $link;
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','notepad');
    return $link;
}
```

Прописал в index.php:

```
require_once 'config.php';
require_once 'functions.php';
```

Как теперь сделать, чтобы в function.php не подключаться каждый раз к БД, как у меня это сейчас прописано?
То есть, к примеру, тут чтобы было так:

```
function saveTask($title,$description){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tasks (title, description) VALUE ('$title','$description')";
    mysqli_query($link,$sql);
}
```

Переменная $link берется из config.php. 
Но в данный момент момент у меня не получается так сделать. Что не так указываю?

База: MySql.
Язык: PHP

Comment: Вы уже выяснили, что Ваше соединение с базой - потоко-безопасно?

Comment: О безопасности, в данный момент, речи никакой не идет. Всё на локалке. Просто нужно вывести в один файл (config.php) соединение с базой и в functions.php уже прописав в mysqli_query ($link, ***) было соединение с базой. В данный момент пишет:Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given  ( вообщем, не видит он мою переменную объявленную в config.php )

Comment: а Вы где-нибудь вызвали `connectToDB()`?

Comment: Пробовал. Не работает.

Comment: Самый простой вариант: использовать global (ЗЛО!!!) либо передавать `$link` в качестве параметра `function saveTask($title,$description,$link)`

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать вот так:

```
function connectToDB() {
    static $link;
    return !isset($link) ? $link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','notepad') : $link; 
}
```

если коннекта не было установлено - он его создаст и запишет в переменную. если коннект уже был - оно просто возвратит его.
И тогда далее если Вам где-то требуется коннект - то вызываете просто connectToDB()

Comment: Пишет: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function connectToDB() . Добавил в функцию так: function saveTask($title,$description){
  $sql = "INSERT INTO tasks (title, description) VALUE ('$title','$description')";
  mysqli_query(connectToDB(),$sql);
}

Comment: проверьте, подключен ли файл с этой функцией. а так рекомендую вам использовать шаблон Александра, но лучше перепишите его в ООП.

Comment: всё это очень странно - как может функции не быть, если вы делаете require_once файла с этой функцией? проверьте еще раз содержимое файлов - попробуйте убрать всё вообще из них - оставьте только то, что написали нам в вопросе (ну и данные для коннекта, конечно).

Comment: Всё работает, если в файле functions.php прописываю require_once 'config.php';
без него functions не видит config.php. Хотя, на главной странице сначала подключается config.php, потом functions.php.

Answer (score 0):

Набросал схему, по которой вам надо будет действовать в ваших функциях. Скопируйте код целиком в отдельный файл, и посмотрите на его результат в браузере -- таким образом вам станет понятен его смысл :

```
connectToDB(); // Обязательный вызов ДО ф-ции saveTask()

echo saveTask(); // Выведет: connectToDB


function connectToDB() {
    global $link;
    $link = __FUNCTION__;

    return $link;
}

function saveTask() {
    global $link;

    return $link;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно Вас понял, то функция saveTask должна выглядеть так:

```html
function saveTask($title,$description){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tasks (title, description) VALUE ('$title','$description')";
    mysqli_query(connectToDB(),$sql);
}
```

Переменной $link в вашем коде неоткуда взяться. А так connectToDB() вернёт как раз ту самую переменную $link

P.S. Сделайте var_dump($link) в saveTask()

Comment: Мне просто, как я понимаю, нужно сделать переменную $link глобальной. Пробовал так прописать: function connectToDB() {
  global $link;
  return !isset($link) ? $link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','notepad') : $link;
} . Всё ровно не видит её в functions.php...

Comment: Пробовали сделать как я написал? Сейчас у Вас в коде $link неоткуда взяться. И либо делать её глобальной, либо передовать как параметр в функцию, либо вызов connectToDB()